# Javascript to get last value of json object

Tags: javascript, object, get, element

I need the last element from the json object like that:

```
{
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "price": [
          "95",
          "80"
        ],
      },
      {
        "price": "68"
      },

.....
```

This is my function:

```
function transform(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.results.collection1.length; i++){
    var price = data.results.collection1[i].price;
    data.results.collection1[i].price = price[price.length-1];
  }

  return data;
}
```

I need to get last value of price. In first one it will be 80 in second 68. When I use

```
price_last = data.collection.price[data.collection.price.length-1];
```

it gives me 80 for first price element and 8 in second.. But I need 68.

Comment: What is the rule to get `80` in the first `price` array ?

Comment: That JSON doesn't seem to have a clear schema.

Comment: the rule is data.collection.price[data.collection.price.length-1]; for the first one it works (because it is an array) but for the second one it cuts 68 and makes 8.

Comment: I can't give clear schema because the total json is too long. This is only a small part.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
if (Array.isArray(data.collection.price)) {
    price_last = data.collection.price[price.length-1];
} else {
    price_last = data.collection.price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the first `price` property is an array and the second is a string. Ideally, you would make `price` an array even if you only have one price.

Failing that, you have to check if the `price` property is an array or not:

```
data.collection.price instanceof Array ? 
    data.collection.price[data.collection.price.length - 1] : 
    data.collection.price;
```

This statement will take the last element if it's an array or just return the price property if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this

```
function transform(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.collection1.length; i++) {
            var price = data.results.collection1[i].price;
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(price) === '[object Array]'){
                data.results.collection1[i].price = price[price.length - 1];
            } else {
                data.results.collection1[i].price = price;
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Note: Array.isArray is an Ecmascript 5 function and might not be defined in all enviroments.

Comment: He edited the question. The original had errors. He was referencing [price] wich was undefined

Answer (score -1):

Try
    data.collection1[data.collection1.length - 1].price;